# Hide a control if a forms if data entry mode is New - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Would anybody know how to determine what a forms data entry mode is from within VB.

The reason for doing this is to be able to hide/show controls depending on whether or not the user is adding or editing records eg:

```
if Me.DataEntry = New then
Me.comboBoxForEdits.Visible = false
end if
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Cheers

Noel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
If Me.NewRecord Then
   Me.SomeControl.Visible=false
End If
```

Comment: Thats great Remou cheers. I was trying to use "If Me.NewRecord = True Then ..." Rookie mistake!

Comment: I'm not sure why what you say you were using wouldn't have worked, since Me.NewRecord returns a Boolean and in VB/VBA True is evaluated as Boolean True.

Comment: Hi David, Have tried the code with "Me.NewRecord = True" and yes it most definitely works. Slightly confused as to what I was using earlier that never worked. Nevertheless, thanks for clarifying the issue. Cheers Noel

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    If Me.AllowAdditions = True Then
        ' set controls as required.
    End If    
End Sub
```

Adding that code to the forms Current event should work.

Comment: You can Allow Additions without the user being in the act of adding a record.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write this code could be:

```
  Me!SomeControl.Visible = Not Me.NewRecord
```

It would be somewhat different from @Remou's code. This would be the equivalent of the above:

```
  If Me.NewRecord Then
     Me!SomeControl.Visible = False
  Else
     Me!SomeControl.Visible = True
  End If
```

Now, it could very well be that you don't want to change the control's .Visible property if it's not a new record, so @Remou's original suggestion may be correct.

Another suggestion is if you are performing this operation on large numbers of controls, you might want to create a custom collection in the form's OnLoad event and have the collection hold pointers to controls you want to operate on. I do this all the time when I need to change the values/appearance/visibility of large numbers of controls in the OnCurrent event.

Comment: Cheers David great advice, I appreciate the help. Will take a look at creating a custom collection, this could be a very useful technique.
Thanks 
Noel

Comment: In regard to custom collections, have a look at this post of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917981/how-to-use-controls-collection-in-access-2003-and-vba/1932103#1932103