# Access VBA - How would I have a loop in VBA that allows me to loop through control names

Tags: ms-access, loops, vba

I have about 10 text boxes on a form that are actually used for display not entry. They are are named `txt_001_Name`, `txt_002_Title`, etc..what kind of loop is used for this.

What kind of VBA should I use to actually loop through the names of the text boxes? So if I was to debug.print it would look like:

```
txt_001_Title
txt_002_Title
txt_003_Title
```

This is probably pretty simple to do - all the more reason that I should learn how!

EDIT: Sorry, I should have been more descriptive about this.

Because of the above naming convention, I am looking to iterate through these text boxes so that I can perform something with each. What each of these 10 text boxes actually represent is numeric values, each having a SQL statement behind them in the form's `onload` event. I also have another set of ten that hold numeric values that are much more static, and finally another ten that use an expression to simply divide each of the first ten, against the relative "second" ten, and the value ends up in the relative 3. So basically it ends up looking like a dashboard table.

```
'first ten'       'second ten'     'resulting ten'
---------------------------------------------------
txt_001_value      txt_001_calc     txt_001_result
txt_002_value      txt_002_calc     txt_002_result
```

etc.

So I actually want to use this for the 'resulting' text boxes. I want to loop through the first ten and perform this easy calculation:

```
 me.txt_001_result = me.txt_001_value / me.txt_001_calc
```

All the naming conventions "match up", so I can manually type out the 10 lines of the above for this, but I am sure there is a better way (loop through this), and I should probably learn it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can list the names of textbox controls with a simple procedure like this:

```vb
Public Sub TextBoxNames(ByRef pfrm As Form)
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In pfrm.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            Debug.Print ctl.Name
        End If
    Next ctl
    Set ctl = Nothing
End Sub
```

You could call it from the form's Load event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    TextBoxNames Me
End Sub
```

However, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  I realize you want to do something with *ctl.Name* other than `Debug.Print`, but I don't know what that is.

Rather than computing a result for *me.txt_001_result* and then assigning that value to the text box, consider setting the control source for *txt_001_result* to *txt_001_value / txt_001_calc* and let Access put the proper value into *txt_001_result* for you.

In response to your comments, I'll suggest this procedure as a starting point for you to build upon:

```vb
Public Sub MyTextBoxValues()
    Const cintLastTextBoxNum As Integer = 10
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strValueControl As String
    Dim strCalcControl As String
    Dim strResultControl As String
    Dim strPrefix As String

    For i = 1 To cintLastTextBoxNum
        strPrefix = "txt_" & Format(i, "000")
        'txt_001_value      txt_001_calc     txt_001_result '
        strValueControl = strPrefix & "_value"
        strCalcControl = strPrefix & "_calc"
        strResultControl = strPrefix & "_result"
        'me.txt_001_result = me.txt_001_value / me.txt_001_calc '
        'Debug.Print strResultControl, strValueControl, strCalcControl '
        Me.Controls(strResultControl) = Me.Controls(strValueControl) / _
            Me.Controls(strCalcControl)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: so i understand what you are saying, but even though I didn't mention it above, i think i need the vba to account for zeros right? also yes you're right, rather than going overboard with descriptions, I am looking to show the result of dividing one text box's value, by another's, in the 'result text' box. so there are acutally way more than 10, but its the exact same idea. and these text boxes are filled with numbers based on another choice that the user selected, based on a choice before that, etc. i use these 'dashboards' all the time because that is what people want ALL THE TIME...( i also

Comment: (cont)..realize that this isn't the intended idea of access but for what i need to get done, it works). so i was looking for a loop that would increment the number of the text box names, in order to perform the bassic calc for each, provided that they contain a value in the first place.

Comment: @Justin I still don't understand enough about the context, but you don't necessarily need VBA code to deal with zero's.  Maybe a VBA function in a textbox's control source expression: IIf(something = 0, "deal with zero", "deal with non-zero")

Comment: @Justin Despite my confusion, did the TextBoxNames procedure give you at least a piece of what you wanted?

Comment: @Hans...yeah I apologize. I think this may boil down to my lack of understand how to explain it. And yes the first example you gave helped me tremendously. So i started out just thinking that there must be some loop to go through all the text boxes that are applicable to the equation, so that I did not have to type of the equation for every set of relative text boxes. i suppose the idea was looping through the 'numeric' value of the text box. so the loop would do this first: txt_001_result = txt_001_value / txt_001_calc if all both are not null/empty, an

Comment: @Hans (cont)....d then do this: txt_002_result = txt_002_value / txt_002_calc, and etc through all text boxes that hold a value of that specific name.

Comment: @Justin Can you use the MyTextBoxValues procedure and make the Me.Controls assignment conditional on: `If Nz(Me.Controls("strCalcControl")) <> 0`

Comment: @HanUps.....yes that helped a lot....I actually figured out how to do is based on the examples....I was just trying to put two ideas into one loop, which may be possible, but once I used two it was quite easy actually. thanks Hans!

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use a FOR EACH to iterate through the controls collection of whatever the textboxes are on (either the form itself or a panel control)

```
dim myBox as Textbox
For each myBox in myForm
    myBox.Text = "hello"
Next
```

Also means you can make custom groups (by putting them all on the same container). 
Note that if you have *other* controls, you might need a typecheck in there (`IF TYPEOF(myBox) = "TextBox" THEN ...`)

You could also do it like:

```
dim i as integer
For i = 1 to 10
     myForm.Controls("txt_00" & i & "_Title").Text = "hello"
Next i
```

I definitely prefer the For Each, though.

Comment: As a note, in Access VBA, you want to use .Value, not .text (.text is used in a different context then VB, and the control has to have the focus for .text to be useable). So, .Value = "some string" is the correct syntax

Comment: Albert is correct, you could use .text, you would just have to set the focus each time, so may as well use value! But BradC's answer works wonderfully!

Answer (score 2):

I can't entirely understand why you need to do what you're doing, but I've had forms like that where I had an unbound form that I wanted to display an arbitrary number of fields, so I can see it. If you're walking the collection of controls only in the form's OnOpen event, that's fine. But if you're doing it in the OnCurrent of a bound form, or multiple times in an unbound form, you might consider a long post of mine on [using custom collections to manage groups of controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917981/how-to-use-controls-collection-in-access-2003-and-vba/1932103#1932103).