# Get the field name in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I try to get field name in VBA.
All I get is the result text, or the complete code.
I just want the field name.

[image]

I try `field.Code`, give me : `{ MERGEFIELD  NAME  \* MERGEFORMAT }`
or `field.Result`, give me the merged result.

Sorry for french Word.

Comment: You are trying to get the name of the text box?  By stepping through all of the controls on the form?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916857/access-vba-how-would-i-have-a-loop-in-vba-that-allows-me-to-loop-through-contr

Comment: you wrote what you don't have and you don't wont. Please write also what you expect to get. Give some examples, not one.

Comment: @MichaelBlaustein : I want to get the value through VBA, not Word interface.

Comment: @KazJaw : I try to get the value "NAME" in a field, with VBA, even after a merge. Field.Code or Field.Result doesn't give "NAME"

Comment: Did you get an answer? I'm looking for the same thing

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there isn't any property which allows to get `name` of MailMerge field. Therefore I could suggest the following workaround:

```
Sub qTest()

    Dim tmpFieldCode As String
        tmpFieldCode = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields(1).Code

    Dim tmpFieldName As String
        tmpFieldName = Split(tmpFieldCode, " ")(2)

    Debug.Print tmpFieldCode   '>>  MERGEFIELD Firma
    Debug.Print tmpFieldName   '>>  Firma
End Sub
```