# How to disable/enable multiple combo boxes based on selection on one combo box on access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

When I select option 1 in the main combo box I want to disable all 15 combo boxes, when option 2 is selected I want to disable 10 combo boxes and enable 5 and when option 3 is selected I want to disable 5 combo boxes and enable 10. I am using afterupdate for the main combo box. I am using disbale/enable =True/False for the 15 combo boxes. I was wondering if there is an easy way to do this instead writing individual disable/enable for each combo box may like a loop?

Comment: Consider using Conditional Formatting - no VBA required. Otherwise, yes, looping code would be possible. Common topic.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916857/access-vba-how-would-i-have-a-loop-in-vba-that-allows-me-to-loop-through-contr

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 15 combos with name like cbo01, cbo02, ...and so on.
and you set the enabled property from option group name frameCombos (has 3 options in it).

Maybe this is the easy way you're wondering for. Maybe.

```
Private Sub FrameCombos_AfterUpdate()
    disableCombos Me.FrameCombos.Value
End Sub

Private Sub disableCombos(optVal As Byte)
    Dim i As Byte, j As String
    Const prefixCbo As String = "cbo"
            
    Select Case optVal
        Case 1
        'disable all combos
            For i = 1 To 15
                If i < 10 Then
                    j = "0" & i
                Else
                    j = i
                End If
                
                Me.Controls(prefixCbo & j).Enabled = False
                
            Next i
            
        Case 2
        'disable 10 combos (cbo01, ..., cbo10)
        'enable 5 combos (cbo11, ..., cbo15)
            For i = 1 To 15
                If i < 10 Then
                    j = "0" & i
                Else
                    j = i
                End If
                
                If i <= 10 Then
                    Me.Controls(prefixCbo & j).Enabled = False
                ElseIf i >= 11 And i <= 15 Then
                    Me.Controls(prefixCbo & j).Enabled = True
                End If
                
            Next i
            
        Case 3
        'enable 5 combos (cbo01, ..., cbo05)
        'disable 10 combos (cbo06, ..., cbo15)
            For i = 1 To 15
                If i < 10 Then
                    j = "0" & i
                Else
                    j = i
                End If
                
                If i <= 5 Then
                    Me.Controls(prefixCbo & j).Enabled = False
                ElseIf i >= 6 And i <= 15 Then
                    Me.Controls(prefixCbo & j).Enabled = True
                End If
                
            Next i
        
    End Select
End Sub
```